# Where is local logs for Python on Azure App Service?

Tags: python, azure, azure-web-app-service

if I run locally, I can see my `print()` texts. But even after enable File System App Service Logs, I still don't see any logs, both in `_docker.log` or streaming log. What is the right way to generate local logs for Python on Azure App Service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To close the loop, I ended up making a simple log method

```
def writeLog(log: str):
    basepath = path.dirname(__file__)
    today = date.today()
    filepath = path.abspath(path.join(basepath, "..", "..", "LogFiles", "MyBot_" + today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") + ".log"))
    f = open(filepath, "a+")
    f.write(today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + " " + log)
    f.write("\n")
    f.close()
```

If I don't `close()`, I won't be able to download the file. Putting it in `LogFiles` together with other log files makes it easier to view from VS Code

Answer (score 1):

I was encountering a similar issue.  In my case the logging was inconsistent in relation to the other logs in the container.  In the end it seemed to be more of a log buffering issue, rather than something specific to Azure App Service.   It was solved by setting the following environment variable in Azure App Service: Settings -> Container -> Application Settings

```
PYTHONUNBUFFERED = 1
```

In a docker run command you'd set it as:

```
--env PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
```

Answer (score 0):

I test with a Flask web and set the WSGI_LOG follow this doc:[Configure the FastCGI handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/configure-web-apps-for-iis-windows?view=vs-2019#configure-the-fastcgi-handler), it will create the log however the logs file only have the `StdErr` log, about `StdOut`  it's always blank.

[image]

So I use another solution to redirect the standard output of your scripts to some log file.

```
import sys
sys.stdout = open('D:\\home\\LogFiles\\app.log', 'w')
print("test")
```

You can configure the above code, then publish your code and run it.

[image]

Comment: I thought Python is moving Linux only? I don't have any of these on Linux. I tried this
`basepath = path.dirname(__file__)
filepath = path.abspath(path.join(basepath, "pm2.log"))
sys.stdout = open(filepath, "a+")`
I can see pm2.log file created but there is no log. The file size is 0 and I can't download the file either